# When we should use class expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, function-expression, class-expression

I have recently got to know that we do have class expressions too like function expressions in JS. I know some points about it(MDN) like:

1. Class expressions may omit the class name ("binding identifier"), which is not possible with class statements.
2. Class expressions allow you to redefine (re-declare) classes without throwing a SyntaxError.

I understand what it can help in, but where should be use it? What can be a classical example of using a class expression that can't be achieved with class statements or vice-versa?

Comment: You can say the same about function expressions, can you not? And yet we use them.

Comment: We have used function expressions a lot, but never seen class expressions any where or may be they are not popular as much function expressions are.

Comment: They aren't but consider they are also a very new feature compared to function expressions. Besides, seems like more trouble *disallowing* them and getting inconsistency rather than having them symmetric to functions. There are few use-cases for them here and there like making dynamic mixins to enhance existing classes with. However, how useful they are is a matter of opinion. I think it's a cool feature in theory but I've used it exactly zero times so far. It just isn't *that* useful. At least to code I write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't that many, but any time you're using `class` as a right-hand value, you're automatically using a class expression (just as with `function` expressions).

- One place I've seen `class` expressions used is when wrapping classes:

  ```
  function withLogging(BaseClass) {
       // The object is purely temporary, so we set the
       // name of the class dynamically
       const subclassName = BaseClass.name + "WithLogging";
       const obj = {
           [subclassName]: class extends BaseClass {
               log(msg) { console.log(msg); }
           },
       };
       return obj[subclassName];
  }
  ```

  I'm **not** saying that's a good idea (I'd probably use a mixin, or composition rather than inheritance), but I've seen it done.

  ```js
     
     function withLogging(BaseClass) {
         // The object is purely temporary, so we set the
         // name of the class dynamically
         const subclassName = BaseClass.name + "WithLogging";
         const obj = {
             [subclassName]: class extends BaseClass {
                 log(msg) { console.log(msg); }
             },
         };
         return obj[subclassName];
     }
     
     const X = withLogging(class Example { });
     console.log(X.name);
     new X().log("Hi there");
  ```
- Something that *looks* like a `class` expression but is in fact more exotic than that is default exporting an unnamed class:

  ```
  export default class { /*...*/ }
  ```

  I **really** don't like that one, because A)  I don't like default exports, and B)  I don't like unnamed functions/classes (other than really simple callback functions, for instance to `map` or `new Promise`).

  It's technically an anonymous `class` *declaration* (just as the equivalent would be an anonymous function declaration), but it's very similar to a `class` expression. (The default export case is the only place the specification allows anonymous `class` or function declarations.)
- If you were creating an object with several classes on it:

  ```
  const classes = {
       A: class A { /*...*/ },
       B: class B { /*...*/ },
       C: class C { /*...*/ },
  };
  ```

  (I don't think I've ever done that, but...)

Comment: In the first example, there is no need to assign class into an object. You can directly `return class extends BaseClass { ... }`.

Comment: @user14967413 - That's true **if** you don't mind an anonymous class. The purpose of the temporary object is, as the comment says and the live example shows, to set the `name` of the class dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

Class expressions are often used for subclass factories:

```
function createClass(…) {
    return class extends … {
        …
    };
}
```

This pattern is common e.g. for [React higher-order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) or [one style of mixin implementation](https://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/).

> What can be a classical example of using a class expression that can't be achieved with class statements or vice-versa?

Nothing, really. Just like with function declarations vs expressions, they do not provide a feature that is not achievable with the other, but just offer a syntax that is more pleasing in specific scenarios.